# Show wx.MenuItems's Help String in a determined wx.StatusBar's Field

Tags: python, python-3.x, wxpython, menuitem, statusbar

**Premise:**

I'm creating a little wx.Frame with a wx.StatusBar with 3 Fields, the one on the left and the one on the right smaller and the one on the center bigger.

Now, By Default, when i put the mouse on a wx.MenuItem the wx.StatusBar set as Status Text the wx.MenuItem's Help String in the FIRST wx.StatusBar's Field like in the below picture:

[image]

**Question:**

Now, I want, if it's possible, that in the above situation the wx.MenuItem's Help String in the SECOND FIELD (the biggest one in the center)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `SetStatusBarPane()` for the `frame`
It simply requires you to nominate a pane number (from 0) where the text should be displayed.

[image]

```
import wx

class Test(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self,parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,title="Frame aka Window",size = (300,200))
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.status=self.CreateStatusBar(3)
        self.SetStatusBarPane(1)
        self.status.SetStatusText("Status bar 0",0)
        self.status.SetStatusText("Status bar 2",2)
        menubar=wx.MenuBar()
        firstm=wx.Menu()
        secondm=wx.Menu()

        fm1 = wx.MenuItem(firstm, wx.NewIdRef(), 'New Window\tAlt+N')
        firstm.Append(fm1)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnMenu1, id=fm1.GetId())
        fm2 = wx.MenuItem(firstm, wx.NewIdRef(), 'Open', "Text for the statusbar")
        firstm.Append(fm2)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnMenu2, id=fm2.GetId())
        fm3 = wx.MenuItem(firstm, -1, 'Quit\tAlt+Q')
        firstm.Append(fm3)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnMenu3, id=fm3.GetId())

        sm1 = wx.MenuItem(firstm, wx.ID_ANY, 'Re-Do', "Statusbar Re-Do")
        secondm.Append(sm1)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnsMenu1, id=sm1.GetId())
        sm2 = wx.MenuItem(secondm, wx.ID_ANY, 'Un-Do', "Statusbar Un-Do")
        secondm.Append(sm2)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnsMenu2, id=sm2.GetId())

        menubar.Append(firstm,"File")
        menubar.Append(secondm,"Edit")

        self.SetMenuBar(menubar)

        t = wx.StaticText(panel,-1,"Hello i'm a test", pos=(10,20))

    def OnMenu1(self, event):
        print("Menu item 1",event.GetId())

    def OnMenu2(self, event):
        print("Menu item 2",event.GetId())
        
    def OnMenu3(self, event):
        print("Menu item 3 Quit",event.GetId())
        self.Destroy()
                
    def OnsMenu1(self, event):
        print("2nd Menu item 1",event.GetId())

    def OnsMenu2(self, event):
        print("2nd Menu item 2",event.GetId())

if __name__=='__main__':
    app=wx.App()
    frame=Test(None)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```